# scikit-learn: get original image size from sklearn.datasets.fetch_lfw_pairs()

Tags: python, image, scikit-learn, dataset, size

I am trying to get the data from Labeled Faces in the Wild database, and I am trying to use the function:

```
fetch_lfw_pairs(subset='train', data_home=None, funneled=True, resize=0.5, 
color=False, slice_=slice(70, 195, None), slice(78, 172, None), 
download_if_missing=True)
```

I would like to get the images in the original size of 250x250 or ideally 224x224, but I cannot figure out how to do that using this function. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have tried:

```
fetch_lfw_pairs(subset='train', data_home=None, funneled=True, resize=1, 
color=False, slice_=(slice(224, 224, None), slice(224, 224, None)), 
download_if_missing=True)
```

but this returns an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer:

fetch_lfw_pairs(subset='train', funneled=True, color=True, resize=None, slice_=None, download_if_missing=False)